# Separate Get/Set property in inherited interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, interface

I have two interfaces and one implementation: `IState`, `IEditableState` and`State`, in which I have a single integer property called `Value`.

I want to be using`IState`to **get** this property and`IEditableState` to **set** it.

My code looks thusly:

```
interface IState { int Value { get; } }

interface IEditableState:IState { int Value { set; } }

class State:IEditableState {
    int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Apparently, I get a warning that `IEditableState.Value` implicitely hides `IState.Value` and that I should add the keyword new for clarity. Intuitively, this is the same property so I don't understand why it should be new.

What would be the "clean" way to do this?

Comment: Why you want this .. can you please explain .. Than i might be able to help you

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to better organize code by forcing one to cast an `IState` into `IEditableState` in order to modify it.


Note sure if relevant but in my case, `State` happens to be a singleton which I access through a service locator using `IState`.

Answer (score 2):

In interfaces, there is no way to define virtual/overrides, so you're stuck using a `new` implementation for inherited interfaces - in classes, this will also mean a `Value { get; set; }` and `IState.Value { get; }` side by side, even if the latter is always going to reference the former.

Alternatively, this does come up in the .NET framework itself, and is circumvented by having a separate interface for the `Readonly` variants, such as with [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx), rather than an inherited interface; this allows implementations to have a single property that satisfies those items with the same name in both.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach? implement your interfaces with a method instead of a property, and then explicitly implement the interfaces in `State` and abstract the method calls behind a property `Value`.  Here is a code sample:

```
interface IState { int GetValue(); }

interface IEditableState : IState { void SetValue(int value); }

class State : IEditableState
{
    public int Value
    {
        get 
        { 
            return (this as IState).GetValue(); 
        }
        set
        {
            (this as IEditableState).SetValue(value);
        }
    }

    private int _value;
    int IState.GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    void IEditableState.SetValue(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"new" keyword is needed because property name in both the base and inherited interfaces is same and you also haven't overridden the property of base interface. When this is the case, you need to specify new keyword. In this case you will hide the property of base interface i.e. you will be able to use property of derived interface only.

Another way to do this is to define two separate properties with different names as given below:

```
interface IState { int ValueGet { get; } }

interface IEditableState:IState { int ValueSet { set; } }

class State:IEditableState {
    int ValueGet { get;  }
    int ValueSet { set; }
}
```