# I have an existing interface (with properties) whats the best way to segregate read and write

Tags: c#, properties, interface

Using C# I have an existing interface that I wish to split into read and write interfaces but still keep the original. What is the best way?

I could make 3 independent interfaces:

```
interface IExistingReadWrite{
   int width {get; set;}
}

interface IRead{
   int width {get;}
}

interface IWrite{
   int width {set;}
}
```

Or I could make IExistingReadWrite inheret from IRead and IWrite, so it is clearer to other coders when they look at IExistingReadWrite there are segregated IRead and IWrite interfaces available too...

```
interface IExistingReadWrite: IRead, IWrite{
   new int width {get; set;}
}

interface IRead{
   int width {get;}
}

interface IWrite{
   int width {set;}
}
```

but I now I've had to use 'new' on IExistingReadWrite to shadow the properties in IRead and IWrite otherwise warnings about ambiguity occur. Shadowing is not really my intention I would like IExistingReadWrite to 'pass the work on' to the interfaces it inhereted than define a new property (So there is no opportunity for there being seperate implementations for each of the seperate interfaces occuring). Is there a better way.

Comment: I can suggest you to swap property to method. `IRead` would contains `int ReadWidth()`, `IWrite` would contains `void WriteWidth(int)` and `IExistingReadWrite` would be inheritance both interfaces and you wouldn't be use the `new` keyword, so you wouldn't shadow the `IRead` and `IWrite` methods

Comment: Never had the need for write-only. So in keeping with `IDictionary` and `IReadonlyDictionary`, I sometimes have `IThing` and `IReadonlyThing`, with `IThing` inheriting `IReadonlyThing` and having `new` properties with a setter. Yes, there could be some weird stuff going on with different explicit implementations but then they are probably not by accident. And if you don't (have to) explicitly implement, you get the "right" logic for free. -- So no, I for one don't know of a better way, but this way served me well for years now.

Comment: George Alexandria, I get your point but now it is possible for someone to implement ReadWidth() in a way that gives a different answer to ((IExistingReadWrite)implementation).width

Comment: not necessarily, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37657305/1462295

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separate Get/Set property in inherited interfaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657045/separate-get-set-property-in-inherited-interfaces-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Corak has the best answer so far... Drop inhereting the IWrite interface on IExistingReadWrite, so the solution now looks like...

```
interface IExistingReadWrite : IRead
{
    // Use IWrite interface instead if you require write only.

    int width { get; set; }
}

interface IRead
{
    int width { get; }
}

public interface IWrite
{
    int width {set; }
}
```

This gives OK behaviour. If you require more security you could add an adapter such as:

```
    internal class WriteImpl : IWrite
{
    private IExistingReadWrite worker;
    internal FooWriteImpl(IExistingReadWrite i)
    {
        worker = i;
    }

    public string width
    {
        get { throw new Exception("Dave I cannot let you do that");}
        set { worker.width = value; }
    }
}
```